# Byte bit manipulation with Java

Tags: java, byte, reverse, bit, flip

I need to reverse some bits in a byte (readed from file) and save it to another file. I find no solution on byte layer?!?

```
byte [] input = byte [8];
int count = inputStream.read (input);

// now I want reverse f.e. on byte 4, the first 3 bits 
// examples (01010101 => 10110101 or 11000001 => 00100001)


// then later I write
outputStream.write (input);
```

Thanx

Comment: Try looking into the shift operators.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 1):

You can "flip" bits using bit mask and XOR operator. Java XOR produces int, so you need to do binary AND with 0xFF to get first byte of 4 byte int.

Example code:

```
byte[] input = new byte[] {(byte) 0b11110000, 0b01011111};
int mask = 0b11100000;

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0xff & input[0])); // 11110000
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0xff & input[1])); // 01011111

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i] = (byte) (0xff & input[i] ^ mask);
}

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0xff & input[0])); // 00010000
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0xff & input[1])); // 10111111
```